# class redifinition c++ multiple include

Tags: c++

i got a small problem.
I got Foo and Foo1 and Foo2.
Foo1 and Foo2 are heritages of Foo.
Now i want to include Foo1 and Foo2 to a cpp file to use both, but both needs includeed Foo in their headers so i get a class redifinition cause its like including Foo twice.

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include "person.h"
#include "booking.h"
class account
{
public:
    account ( const std::initializer_list<person> p_PersonList, const std::initializer_list<booking> p_BookingList );
    virtual ~account ( );
protected:
    double m_balance;
    std::vector<person> m_RepresentativesVec;
    std::vector<booking> m_BookingsVec;
};
```

Heritage 1:

```
#pragma once
#include "account.h"
class payments_account : public account
{
public:
    payments_account ( const std::initializer_list<person> p_PersonList, const std::initializer_list<booking> p_BookingList );
    ~payments_account ( );
};
```

2:

```
#pragma once
#include "account.h"
class savings_account : public account
{
public:
    savings_account ( const std::initializer_list<person> p_PersonList, const std::initializer_list<booking> p_BookingList );
    ~savings_account ( );
};
```

if i now want to use the 2 heritages in management.h i get a redifinition compiling error cause account is included twice, but both need to know account in their definition...

Comment: Add `#pragma once` to the first header too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `#pragma once`, I suggest you to use internal `#define` guards:

```
#ifndef _FOO_H_
#define _FOO_H_
/* … */
#endif /* _FOO_H_ */
```

Comment: if the compiler supports it, `#pragma once` is far more elegant. Maybe it's not part of the standard, but IMHO it *should* be part of it, that would be better, more readable, more concise.